# How to restore database before executing test in protractor

Tags: database, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have written E2E tests in Protractor which uses node to run through webdriver.

Now I have some inserts tests which will insert the data and create user.

Now if I run the case for the first time it will pass but when I will rerun the test it will fail as it will already present.

Expected : I need to restore my MSSQL DB when ever the tests in protractor start.

Present : I am doing manually by restoring the test.

Is there any way that I can restore the DB through protractor or Node ?

Answer (score 0):

This is really out of scope for protractor.

Make your grunt or gulp task manager to execute the database restore script before running protractor end-to-end tests. For example, you can use [`grunt-shell`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) package.

See also:

- [Angular Protractor e2e Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471252/angular-protractor-e2e-testing)

Comment: @ alecxe- It would be great if you give example or sample code.

Comment: @RashmiChauhan were you able to solve it via the `grunt-shell`? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe- No , The problem is still there . Can you please give example or sample code?

Comment: @RashmiChauhan well, `grunt-shell` gives you an ability to execute arbitrary shell commands ([sample](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell#run-command)). That said, basically the same things you do to restore the database via the command line, you put into the shell grunt config.