# Resetting database state after running each test case in Protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

So, I have seen a lot of questions[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740837/how-to-restore-database-before-executing-test-in-protractor)  regarding this topic but somehow I don't feel like implementing the answers provided there. For example doing the reset in `beforeAll()` or running a `grunt` task, etc.

Say, I have a spec file which contains 25 tests any of the tests can modify the database state in such a way that the next test may fail. I have a test endPoints in my `API` with higher privilege levels, I was using them to reset the changes done in my individual tests. The problem was if any of the tests threw any exception, the code to reset the database state won't run.

So I decided to have a variable: say, `databaseChanges` which will store the information about any database change done through the test. So whenever I am about to do any database change through my tests I update the `databaseChanges` variable before doing the change. I use this variable to revert my data state in `afterEach()` and reset this `databaseChanges` in `beforeEach()`.

**Question:**
The problem I am facing is I want to validate whether those changes were successful or not. When I use `expect()` statements in `afterEach()`, It throws an error with a message saying something like `èxpect() not allowed outside it(), or a timeout occurred....`, So I believe I can't have `expect()` in my `afterEach()`, or can I? Or is there some way I can run a `it()` inside `afterEach()` but of course that is something looking like an infinite loop.

1. I want to get suggestions on whether what I am doing is a correct way
   to reset the database or I should go with doing it in my
   `beforeAll()`, etc. and
2. Is there some way with which I can validate
       that the database was updated successfully in my `àfterEach()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm organizing the tests, it might be not the best approach but it works for me. First test creates the object, then follow tests that will manipulate with the object and last test deletes the created object. 
Another approach is creation of object to be placed in BeforeAll and delete in AfterAll.