# e2e testing with protractor in angular 2

Tags: mocking, protractor, e2e-testing, angular2-testing

on back-end i use Spring Boot, on front-end i use Angular 2.
i write simple tests for my front-end, but i want to mock my back-end.
i search in google but i do not found answer for my question.
how to mock back-end on testing with protractor?
sorry for my english!
thanks!

i tried this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-mock-backend# but then i found this:  [https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/582411b7ad6c0f9176b231dc51dc328b98affbdf/lib/protractor.js#L717](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYF0K.png)

Comment: if your backend is via REST, then you could use a simple [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) - this is very basic and can be started prior to e2e (e.g. in protractor's `beforeLaunch` callback)

Comment: thanks, it's work for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your backend is via REST, then you could use a simple [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) - this is very basic and can be started prior to e2e (e.g. in protractor's `beforeLaunch` callback)

*(added from comment since it seemed to be a useful answer)*

Comment: An example auto-starting and auto-stopping mocks with node express during e2e tests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45638832/786389

Answer (score 0):

The best way to mock you API's with an Angular 2 app is with [ng-Apimock](https://github.com/mdasberg/ng-apimock). As far as I know the only plugin on the market now that can support local development as well as E2E-testing.

I'm using it in a Angular 2 app for a customer and it works like a charm. There are enough doccs / plugins to get it working with for example grunt, gulp, Anguler-CLI, Angular-seed and so on.

Hope it helps you